# Brute Force Recognising English

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I have written a Java program to Brute force an Encryption algorithm given a chuck of known plain text.  I now want it to recognise English text when it sees it so I know the key but I am unsure of a simple algorithm to detect english text.

I can calculate the Unicity Distance so know how many characters I need to know to be sure the text is English but just need the algorithm.

Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT

Text is plaintext only

Comment: In a ciphertext only attack: As a first step I'd check if bit 7 in bytes is unset. Since English implies ASCII, that is a good early-out. Then filter out control characters. For 16 bytes of plaintext (one AES block) every 5 million'th attempt will pass these tests, at which point you can apply a more expensive test.

Comment: If this is a known plaintext attack, why do you even try to recognize English? You already know the exact plaintext by definition.

Comment: I am now moving away from known plaintext

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best method to check this is to check words against a dictionary. If you only need to verify that the message CONTAINS english, what i would recommend is to just have a dictionary with very common words. You could probably build something effective with maybe 20 words.

Comment: The unicity distance is very low, only 5 characters?

Comment: actually im not that well versed in this topic, so i dont know what unicity is. I know that English language recognition is a common topic here on StackOvrflow, and very often it is recommended to use a dictionary of sorts. I am suggesting that if you only wish to see if its english, as opposed to german, any other language, or complete randomness, you wouldnt need a complete dictionary, as would be used for spellchecking. If you somehow have a more elegant solution, feel free to proceed with this.